# Mint 16 Cinnamon, maximize window fully

Tags: linux-mint, window

I am using Linux Mint 16 Petra cinnamon. The problem I have is that when I drag a window to the top edge of the screen the window only maximizes to the top half of the screen instead of the the entire screen, just like when I hit the maximize button (plus button on the top right side of the screen).

This is what I get.
[image]

This is what I want to happen.
[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Go into System Settings, then into "Window Tiling and Edge Flip" and check the box marked "Maximize, instead of tile, when dragging window to top edge".

Comment: Is there any way to extend this to the keyboard shortcuts? I.e. I want <windows> + <up> to maximize instead of snap to the top of the screen.

Comment: I second this! It's a little thing, but I am sure there would be a flag somewhere to change this default behaviour

Comment: Is there no way to configure the keyboard shortcut too?

Comment: Note that a 2nd <windows>+<up> press (after the first tiles it) maximizes it to whole screen.